# Image browse/upload with KCfinder to own folder in yii

Tags: php, yii, kcfinder

I am using KCFinder 3.0 in a yii website. I have many users so i have to separata the uploaded images so i need to open own folder when the writers want to browse an image from server.
How can i do this?
I have this code

```
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
       filebrowserBrowseUrl: '<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl; ?>/kcfinder/browse.php?type=files',
       filebrowserImageBrowseUrl: '<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl; ?>/kcfinder/browse.php?type=image',
       filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl: '<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl; ?>/kcfinder/browse.php?type=flash',
       filebrowserUploadUrl: '<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl; ?>/kcfinder/upload.php?type=files',
       filebrowserImageUploadUrl: '<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl; ?>/kcfinder/upload.php?type=images',
       filebrowserFlashUploadUrl: '<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl; ?>/kcfinder/upload.php?type=flash'   });
```

If I add the get parameter it is ignored and just browses and uploads to a directory called "files".

```
        CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
           filebrowserBrowseUrl: '<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl; ?>/kcfinder/browse.php?type=2014_10_12',
           filebrowserImageBrowseUrl: '<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl; ?>/kcfinder/browse.php?type=2014_10_12',
           filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl: '<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl; ?>/kcfinder/browse.php?type=2014_10_12',
           filebrowserUploadUrl: '<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl; ?>/kcfinder/upload.php?type=2014_10_12',
           filebrowserImageUploadUrl: '<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl; ?>/kcfinder/upload.php?type=2014_10_12',
           filebrowserFlashUploadUrl: '<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl; ?>/kcfinder/upload.php?type=2014_10_12'
  });
```

Comment: http://www.xms-systems.co.uk/articles_read.php?a_id=77

Answer (score 0):

If the javascript code you've written is in a **.js** file, the PHP code you've embedded into it **will not be parsed**.

PHP code only gets parsed if it's a **.php** file.

If, on the other hand, you use Yii's [registerScript](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CClientScript#registerScript-detail) method, you can add Javscript code from a PHP file (although you shouldn't do too much of it or your code will be a mess).

For example (on a Yii **view file**):

```
<?php
  $this->breadcrumbs = [
    'Foo',
    'Bar'
  ];
?>

<?php Yii::app()->getClientScript()->registerScript('
    $(document).ready(function{
        console.log("yay");
    }); 
'); ?>
<br />
<br />
<div class="post">
<!-- the rest of your view file.... -->
```

Comment: ty the advice but i dont have problem with js registre. This js is in _form.php .
My problem: how can i browse pictures to own folder with KCFinder 3.0

Comment: You can serve javascript from a php file in an easier way.  Just add a Content-type header at the top:    `<?php Header("Content-type: application/javascript"); $js = 'my javascript;'; echo $js; ?>`